# How does Vega of a call/put behave under the Black-Scholes model?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

I have two questions. I would prefer a reference if possible.

1. Is the value of vega bounded for $\sigma\in [0,\infty)$? (I assume so, I imagine it goes to 0 as $\sigma$ go to infinity.)
2. Are there any well established properties of vega? (e.g. convexity/monotonicity? How fast does it go to 0, as $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$? How does it behave as $\sigma\rightarrow 0$?)

A partial answer would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we write down the formula for vega we get
$$
\text{vega} = S \sqrt{T} e^{-q T} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(- \frac{d_1^2}2)
$$
where
$$
d_1 = \frac{\log(S/K) + (r-q +\sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.
$$
We have 
$$
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  \infty} d_1 = \infty,
$$
as $\sigma^2$ grows quicker than $\sigma$ for $\sigma \rightarrow  \infty$ and therefore
$$
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  \infty} \text{vega} = 0,
$$
due the definition above and the continuous functions involved.

Furthermore 
$$
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  0} d_1 \text{ is unbounded},
$$
because
$$
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  0} d_1 = \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  0} \frac{\log(S/K)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} + \frac{(r-q) \sqrt{T}}{\sigma} +\sigma/2 \sqrt{T}
$$
and the first two summands are unbounded for $\sigma \rightarrow  0$ and the third tends to zero.
Thus depending on $\log(S/K)$ - the moneyness - and $r-q$ we get
$$
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  0} d_1 = \pm \infty
$$
and in any case
$$
 \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow  0} \text{vega} = 0.
$$

For the second part of convexity/monotonicity you need $\frac{\partial \text{vega}}{\partial \sigma}$ this is called [Volga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanna%E2%80%93Volga_pricing).

Wilmot has the formula for Volga [here](http://www.wilmottwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Call_option) but I did not check it. You can analyze it in order to analyze montonicity. You need its derivative for convexity ...

Comment: A convex function cannot be 0 and both 0 and infinity.

Comment: @Lost1 I mean that depending on the constellation of $\log(S/K)$ and $r-q$ which determines the sign we get either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. But as $d_1$ is squared the sign does not matter.